# FFMpeg : Convert image + audio to MP4 60FPS including FadeIn / FadeOut and overlay

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Inputs are an MP3 or WAV, and an image (JPG or PNG)
2. The output should be an MP4 video with the MP3 audio with the image, at 60FPS for a very smooth fade in/fade out (black) on the video (1s each)

I strugguling to make this fade in / fade out.
Here is what I have:

```
 ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 60 -shortest -vf fade=in:0:01 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

My fadein is static, so black image and then my video, not smooth.
How do I get a smooth 60FPS fade?

I also have another request, let's say I have an overlay video that I want to concatenate to my video. If I concatenate a video to the existing video, the overlay will also be on top of the fades which is not right, how can I achieve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `nb_frame=1` with your filter options `in:0:01`. If you wish to fade duration, you need to specify the option name: `in:duration=1` (`start_time=0` option is unnecessary as 0 is the default).

For fadeout, you need to specify the `start_time` option so run `ffprobe` first to get the duration of the mp3 file.

As for the overlay, you must do it before fading. Your filterchain should look like `[0:v][1:v]overlay,fade:in,fade:out`

[addendum] Fading effect requires frames to realize it, increase the framerate before the filter `fade`: `[0:v][1:v]overlay,fps=60,fade:in,fade:out`. And remove `-r 60` from the output option (or leave it in as it shouldn't do anything anyway).

Comment: Thank you for all these useful informations! Fade duration doesn't work either : black image for 1s and then my video, it seems that my video is at 1 frame which is not true because I can see with a right click on my video that it's 60FPS

Comment: Ah, I know what the problem is, your input framerate is 1. So you have no intermediate frames to realize the fade. See the post update

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you!!